# Deriving the change in a Poisson lambda over time

Tags: poisson-distribution

I have two sample data sets which are each a 1x95 vector containing the $\lambda$ of a Poisson. Each slot contains the $\lambda$ for the minute that the slot represents. So t1[1] is the starting lambda, t1[2] is the $\lambda$ after one minute, etc. The value of the lambda slowly decays over the time series. The series only goes from 1 to 95 minutes.

Based on these data sets, is it possible to derive the formula for this decay? I would like to have a formula that could then take a value between say 1.1 and 6.0 and return a vector of $\lambda$'s for each slot 1:95.

In other words, I would like to have a function :-

```
new_lambda <- function(beginning_lambda, current_minute)
```

The first data set is for initial $\lambda$, 1.4, and the second is for $\lambda$, 2.1. (The first element of each vector is the initial $\lambda$, and each subsequence number is the decayed lambda after slot number minutes)

```
c(1.4, 1.38731693971954, 1.37461497531924, 1.36189387488779, 
1.34915340111498, 1.33639331110529, 1.32361335618285, 1.31081328168731, 
1.29799282676014, 1.2851517241207, 1.27228969983157, 1.25940647305241, 
1.24650175578168, 1.23357525258547, 1.22062666031263, 1.20765566779532, 
1.19466195553401, 1.18164519536608, 1.16860505011665, 1.1555411732307, 
1.14245320838518, 1.12934078907955, 1.11620353820353, 1.1030410675802, 
1.08985297748287, 1.07663885612371, 1.06339827911211, 1.05013080888051, 
1.03683599407519, 1.02351336890948, 1.0101624524762, 0.996782748016363, 
0.983373742140467, 0.969934903998559, 0.956465684394797, 0.942965514841851, 
0.929433806549955, 0.915869949344926, 0.902273310508843, 0.888643233536399, 
0.874979036799168, 0.861280012109178, 0.847545423172193, 0.833774503919968, 
0.819966456709522, 0.806120450375986, 0.792235618123945, 0.77831105524032, 
0.764345816609622, 0.750338914009939, 0.736289313165104, 0.72219593052513, 
0.708057629743121, 0.693873217812284, 0.679641440821358, 0.665360979280522, 
0.651030442962453, 0.636648365194487, 0.622213196527442, 0.607723297694309, 
0.593176931757131, 0.578572255322537, 0.563907308684732, 0.549180004728389, 
0.534388116391651, 0.519529262449729, 0.504600891330413, 0.489600262611446, 
0.474524425772686, 0.459370195678448, 0.444134124141028, 0.428812466756316, 
0.413401143994426, 0.397895695255455, 0.382291224238561, 0.366582333486939, 
0.350763045311143, 0.334826705383382, 0.318765864022086, 0.302572128373676, 
0.286235976070479, 0.269746517053042, 0.253091184349661, 0.236255325435227, 
0.219221651093633, 0.201969474329622, 0.18447362979703, 0.166702888088314, 
0.148617533565322, 0.130165475875085, 0.11127559850736, 0.0918453826079598, 
0.0717150018886348, 0.0506024484826778, 0.0278795484294726)

c(2.1, 2.08097540957931, 2.06192246297887, 2.04284081233169, 
2.02373010167247, 2.00458996665794, 1.98542003427428, 1.96621992253097, 
1.94698924014021, 1.92772758618105, 1.90843454974735, 1.88910970957861, 
1.86975263367252, 1.85036287887821, 1.83093999046895, 1.81148350169297, 
1.79199293330102, 1.77246779304913, 1.75290757517497, 1.73331175984606, 
1.71367981257777, 1.69401118361933, 1.67430530730529, 1.6545616013703, 
1.63477946622431, 1.61495828418557, 1.59509741866817, 1.57519621332076, 
1.55525399111279, 1.53527005336422, 1.5152436787143, 1.49517412202454, 
1.4750606132107, 1.45490235599784, 1.4346985265922, 1.41444827226278, 
1.39415070982493, 1.37380492401739, 1.35340996576327, 1.3329648503046, 
1.31246855519875, 1.29192001816377, 1.27131813475829, 1.25066175587995, 
1.22994968506428, 1.20918067556398, 1.18835342718592, 1.16746658286048, 
1.14651872491443, 1.12550837101491, 1.10443396974766, 1.08329389578769, 
1.06208644461468, 1.04080982671843, 1.01946216123204, 0.998041468920782, 
0.97654566444368, 0.95497254779173, 0.933319794791163, 0.911584946541464, 
0.889765397635697, 0.867858382983806, 0.845860963027097, 0.823770007092583, 
0.801582174587476, 0.779293893674594, 0.75690133699562, 0.734400393917169, 
0.711786638659029, 0.689055293517672, 0.666201186211542, 0.643218700134474, 
0.620101715991639, 0.596843542883182, 0.573436836357841, 0.549873500230409, 
0.526144567966714, 0.502240058075073, 0.478148796033129, 0.453858192560515, 
0.429353964105719, 0.404619775579563, 0.379636776524491, 0.35438298815284, 
0.32883247664045, 0.302954211494433, 0.276710444695545, 0.250054332132471, 
0.222926300347984, 0.195248213812627, 0.16691339776104, 0.13776807391194, 
0.107572502832952, 0.0759036727240167, 0.041819322644209)
```

Any pointers or hints would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A trivial way to do this is just to rescale the $\lambda_i$ by the input $\lambda$ value, and return the appropriate rescaled $\lambda_i$:

```
new_lambda <- function(beginning_lambda, current_minute)
{
  fval <- c(2.1, 2.08097540957931, 2.06192246297887, 2.04284081233169, 
     2.02373010167247, 2.00458996665794, 1.98542003427428, 1.96621992253097,
     ..., 
     0.0759036727240167, 0.041819322644209)
  fval[current_minute] * beginning_lambda / fval[1]
}
```

Since your second list appears (from a test of the first, second, and last values) to be exactly 1.5 times your first list, you don't need both lists.  This is all you really need, at least given your stated objective.